# LibGDX RoboVM Package for App Store .ipa crashes after splash screen

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I have an libGDX iOS application that works perfectly when testing in Eclipse via Run as iOS Device or Run as Simulator. However, when I use RoboVM Tools ->  Package for App Store to get an .IPA file that I install on my iPad, it crashes after the libGDX splash screen.

It isn't a problem with provisionals or certificates since my Run Configurations are exactly the same as the options I used to export.

This problem seems to be pretty common after gradle build, but I have not found a solution yet. Can someone shed some light?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Now it has been fixed. [Solution is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34529116/5730512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem (run without problems on simulator/device, but crash on Testflight by using ad-hoc generation). I fix it by upgraded libGDX / RoboVM version

Set libGDX in version 1.1.0 and RoboVM to the 0.14 snapshot (maybe not stable, but my game doesn't crash anymore)

I give you my gradle setting :

allprojects 
{

```
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'flappy_gobelin'
        gdxVersion = '1.1.0'
        roboVMVersion = '0.0.14-SNAPSHOT'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I used the box2d in my project. And I got the same problem.

I created lib folder in iOS project, then copy the gdx-box2d-1.1.0.jar to that folder, and add it to the build path.
The .ipa file worked.

(But it still didn't work on iOS 8.0)

Comment: Please avoid saying that something "works". "The .ipa file can be created." "The app still crashes on iOS." Also this does not seem to be an answer since it does not solve the problem.